# how to change actionbar color using AppCompactActivity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the action bar color in blue but always is black, I'm using to files for styles : styles.xml and styles-21.xml.
This the code in styles-21.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_color_900</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/purple_color_200</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="@android:background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
</style>
```

and this is the style for styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_color_900</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_color_200</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue_color_50</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
</style>
```

My class inheritance from AppCompatActivity...

Any help with that?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) from official android docs. You should use not only `android:actionBarStyle` but `actionBarStyle` too while using compatibility lib.

Comment: link is broken @dilix

Comment: Yes, link was removed from docs, you could check cpy here: http://www.androiddocs.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html or use relevant android docs from https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to change the color of your Action Bar :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mainColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/mainColorDark</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/mainColor</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

<color name="mainColor">#E41F26</color>
```

The Action Bar will be colored with mainColor defined at the end ! I Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, you were right this is the code fix it:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue_color_900</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/purple_color_200</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue_color_50</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue_color_500</item>
</style>
```